# DotNetNuke CustomValidator strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, customvalidator

I have a strange problem with a dotnetnuke module I'm developing.
I want to use a asp custom validator to validate some input. To keep it simple I'll check only if the field was not empty and at least a few characters long. (I know there are other standard validators that I can use).

The problem is that my code works ok locally (development), but not on production.
The only difference I know is that I use DNN 6 instead of DNN 5.

No matter what I type in on production site, it always shows me the validation error message.

These are the relevant parts of the webpage:

**ASCX:**

```
<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelValidationSummaryHome" ChildrenAsTriggers="False"                          UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" CssClass="validationSummary" runat="server"
            EnableClientScript="False" ShowSummary="true" ShowMessageBox="false" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorActiveTab" runat="server" Display="None"
            ErrorMessage="Error the field ... was not correct..." OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorActiveTab_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

```
<asp:Button ID="btnZoeken" CssClass="btnZoeken" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"    Text="<%$ Resources:GLOBAL, btnZoeken %>"
        OnClick="btnZoeken_Click" />
```

**Code behind**

```
private bool ValidateTab_Ondernemingsnummer()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOndernemingsnummer.Text) &&  txtOndernemingsnummer.Text.Length >= 3)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

protected void CustomValidatorActiveTab_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        int activeTab = GetActiveIndexAccordion();

        switch (activeTab)
        {
            //Zoeken op ondernemingsnummer
            case 0:
                if (!ValidateTab_Ondernemingsnummer())
                {
                    e.IsValid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.IsValid = true;
                }
                break;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED:

I used dotnetnuke logging to see when and why e.isValid is set to false.
My custom validator control was being called twice!!
The first time it was validated ok, the second time it was not.

My solution was to disable custom server validator control in the markup and enable it just after doing the submit (and don't forget to turn it off).

Like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelValidationSummaryHome" ChildrenAsTriggers="False"
    UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" CssClass="validationSummary" runat="server"
            EnableClientScript="False" ShowSummary="true" ShowMessageBox="false" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorActiveTab" runat="server" Display="None"
            EnableClientScript="false" Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="ERROR ONDERNEMINGSNUMMER"
            OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorActiveTab_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Enabled = false is important here!

Then in the button click

```
protected void btnZoeken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomValidatorActiveTab.Enabled = true;
        CustomValidatorActiveTab.Validate();

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            CustomValidatorActiveTab.Enabled = false;
```

I still don't know why the CustomValidatorActiveTab_ServerValidate was being called twice.
It has something to do with DNN 5 I suppose (and maybe it was fixed in DNN 6).

I hope this helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the validator is called twice is due to the `link button`.
Generating the GridView `onBubbleEvent`, which also causes the `validator` to validate.